# How to check if a schema index already exists for a node's property in neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using [IndexDefinition](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0-M03/org/neo4j/graphdb/schema/IndexDefinition.html) for populating index over a given property in neo4j.

```
IndexDefinition indexDefinition = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label("Person")).on("NodeType").create();
```

Problem is when I execute the program again with similar code for Index population, I get following exception.

```
 org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.schema.AlreadyIndexedException: Already indexed :label[0](property[0]).
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.DataIntegrityValidatingStatementContext.checkIndexExistence(DataIntegrityValidatingStatementContext.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.DataIntegrityValidatingStatementContext.indexCreate(DataIntegrityValidatingStatementContext.java:78)
```

I just want to check if an Index for a property is already there, then no subsequent Index population should take place.

Comment: Just ignore the exception if it already exists?

Comment: that's not a solution.

Comment: And why isn't it a solution?

Comment: @fge poor programming

Comment: @KarlMorrison disagree; it is like people checking whether a row with an id exists before inserting it into the database: it is a waste; just try and insert, if it already exists, well, you can tell by the error which is returned.

Comment: @fge I suppose it depends on the type of application you are building. You are assuming there are no other bugs in your code and that the database is setup correctly. If a bug does exist not handling data correctly can result in catastrophic consequences especially in enterprise size applications.

Comment: @KarlMorrison what do you believe tests are for? ;) I have proceeded this way for years and years without a single problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you check the Indexes for a Label before trying to create it and getting a (correct) exception?

http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0-M03/org/neo4j/graphdb/schema/Schema.html#getIndexes(org.neo4j.graphdb.Label)

Comment: Downvote. Link only answer and the link takes you to a default page at Neo4j for broken links.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helper function that I'm using in my code, so I don't forget to wrap it in a tx.

```
/**
 * Helper method to get indexes by Label, wrapped in a tx
 * 
 * @param label
 * @return one or more IndexDefinitions to iterate over, or null if there
 *         were none matching the label.
 */
public Iterable<IndexDefinition> getIndexByLabel(Label label) {
    Iterable<IndexDefinition> x = null;
    try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
        x = graphDb.schema().getIndexes(label);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Downvote. Question is about index on property, this answer is about index on label.