# Java - Check if index already exists neo4j (if clause)

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm actually building onto the question: [How to check if a schema index already exists for a node's property in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718076/how-to-check-if-a-schema-index-already-exists-for-a-nodes-property-in-neo4j)

I can however not find how to do the actual if clause. For example:

```
label = DynamicLabel.label("Label");
Iterable<IndexDefinition> indexes = schema.getIndexes(label);
for(IndexDefinition index : indexes) {
    if(index.equals(schema.indexFor(label).on("id"))) {
        // index exists on property "id" on label "Label"!
    }
}
```

This however isn't working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet should help:

```
label = DynamicLabel.label("Label");
Iterable<IndexDefinition> indexes = schema.getIndexes(label);
for(IndexDefinition index : indexes) {
    for (String key: index.getPropertyKeys()) {
         if (key.equals("id")) {
              return true; // index for label and property exists
         }
    }
}
return false; // no matching schema index
```

Please note that in Neo4j 2.0/2.1 each index has only one single property. Multi property indexes are not yet supported - however the API is already designed for that.

Comment: Perfect! Interesting about the multiple indexes, it's actually what I wish to achieve (multiple indexes that is). Any advice what to do for the meantime?

Comment: You can have multiple indexes on the same label using exactly one property each. The suggested workaround if you want to spawn a single index over multiple properties is to use a concatenated property containing all parts and index that one.