# How to check existed Indexes in Neo4j-jdbc?

Tags: neo4j

I know there exists solution in embedded neo4j, which describe in "[Java - Check if index already exists neo4j (if clause)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443337/java-check-if-index-already-exists-neo4j-if-clause)"

But since I have to use neo4j remotely and control transactions by myself, I develop my project with neo4j-jdbc which doing anything by cypher.

I want to write methods to create/drop indexes dynamically, but how can I know which index already in neo4j? I can use `:schema` in admin interface, but it not works in Cypher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not yet possible with `cypher-jdbc`. You might file github issue for a [feature request](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/issues/new).

As a workaround you can get a list of indexes using the [REST api](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-schema-indexes.html#rest-api-list-indexes-for-a-label).